# The type 'xxxx' already contains a definion for 'xxx'

Tags: asp.net

I am working in Asp.net 2010 C#
Inside my web page,

```
public partial class NewStore : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public class Item()
    {
       public int ItemID;
       public string ItemName;
    }
}
```

The Problem is that When I rebuild the Project then an error occurs 'The type 'NewStore' already contains a definion for 'Item'.

I didnt find any other class Item inside the Page... Will u please help me..

Comment: self explanatory. change the className and remove parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

Remove `parenthesis` after class name `Item`.

```
public class Item
{
   public int ItemID;
   public string ItemName;
}
```